# Start the application in crontab using another user

Tags: linux, cron

I want to create a small monitor script for our tomcat.

But I met some problems may you could give me some hint.

At first, our tomcat must be started as a special local users, let's call it local_user, and in crontab, I try to change the user role like this (a simple demo):

```
echo "aaa" >> gg.txt    
su - local_user -c "echo Nihao >> gg.txt"    
su - local_user -c "echo Nihao >> /tmp/gg.txt"
```

But I found aaa could be printed in the gg.txt, but for Nihao never be printed into this file and it seems this was not executed.

Anyone know how to do this?

Br,
Tim

Comment: Does `local_user` have write permission to `gg.txt`?

Comment: Yeah, it have, because the crontab is created by this local user.

Comment: And the aaa could be printed to this file.

Comment: If this is local_users's crontab, why are you using `su` to switch to the same user?

Comment: Because in default, this crontab should be started by root. For example, when I startup a tomcat, the startup user is not local_user, it is root.

Comment: When `su` is used by a normal user, it asks for a password. Your crontab commands can't answer the password prompt.

Comment: @Barmar np, local_user is a local user and no need for input the passwd.   For this script, if I remove the crontab, then I can run it successfully. Not sure if crontab make some limitation.

Comment: You mean the user doesn't have a password? What is its login shell?

Comment: It have the passwd, if I try to using su for our company id, then I have to input the passwd, but for this local user, no need for me to input the passwd.

Comment: You're confusing me. If it has a password, you have to enter it, unless you're root. I don't know what you mean by it's a local user, what other kind of user is there?

Comment: Dont know how to prove this, It just dont need passwd. I can directly using su local_user to switch. But if I use the su my_id, my_id is my company user id, then I have to input the passwd.

Comment: Glad I didn't post that as an answer, since I have no idea why it's failing.

Comment: It is ok,still thanks for your answer.